# What happens to items equipped to a character that leaves the party?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

I reached a point in the story where a player character has left my party. Specifically:

> When Vandam is killed at the end of Chapter 3.

What happened to the items and aux cores I had equipped to that character and their blade? Were they returned to my inventory, or are they gone forever? (I'd check my inventory, but I don't remember what items I'd equipped them with.)

Answer (score 2):

I can't 100% confirm this yet, but I believe it to be the case:

- When a character leaves the party temporarily, their accessories and aux cores remain equipped, but you still have access to them and can take them back to put on someone else.
- When a character leaves the party permanently, their accessories and aux cores are unequipped and returned to inventory.